# Springboot data - No property registration found

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to return data from a mongo database using springboot data and jdbc

here is my POM.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The Issue I'm having is that I'm only able to perform .findAll() on my repository. When I try to use my custom method of

```
.getAllByRegistration_numberIs(VehRegId);
```

I get an error,

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>   Error creating bean with name 'readService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'vr'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vehicleRegistrationRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: **No property registration found** for type vehicle_registration!

**My Service**

```
@Component
public class ReadService {

    @Autowired
    VehicleRegistrationRepository vr;

    public List<vehicle_registration> getReg(String VehRegId) {

        //This works
        //return (List<vehicle_registration>) vr.findAll();

        //This doesn't work
        return (List<vehicle_registration>) vr.getAllByRegistration_numberIs(VehRegId);
    }

}
```

**My Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface VehicleRegistrationRepository extends CrudRepository<vehicle_registration, String> {

    vehicle_registration getAllByRegistration_numberIs(String VehRegNo);

}
```

And my **Object**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class vehicle_registration {
    /*
    This class must have the same name as the collection in mongodb
     */

    @Id
    String _id;

    Integer OwnID;
    Integer mileage_of_lasttransfer;
    Date date_of_registration;
    Date date_of_last_transfer;
    String registration_number;
    String UUID;
    String personUUID;
    String vehicleUUID;
    Date time_stamp;
}
```

Comment: classes in java should start with an uppercase letter, use the `@Document` annotation to get a reference to the collection. A method that returns multiple entities (get**All**) will need `List<VehicleRegistration>` (or any iterable) as return type, change this in your Repository. The repository should be named like the entity class, so it should be `VehicleRegistration` -> `VehicleRegistrationRepository`. Also make sure that the file holding VehicleRegistration is named like the class. I wouldn't use all the underscores for your properties, use the `@Field` annotation instead. jdbc is for sql

Comment: Try to use this dependency spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb. If I remember correctly spring translates underscores to camelCase

Comment: Hi, I made those changes so its VehicleRegistration and VehicleRegistrationRepository returning to a list and get the same error.

Comment: Do you want to get registration_number field from vehicle_registration entity? @Kaigo

Comment: Did you rename the properties as well?

Comment: Yep "registration_number": "J75787" from vehicleRegistration collection I'm trying to get.
Not sure what you mean, rename the properties?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Repository
public interface VehicleRegistrationRepository extends CrudRepository<vehicle_registration, String> {

    List<vehicle_registration> findAllByRegistrationNumber(String VehRegNo);

}
```

You can find the how you can write query with spring data jpa [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) Besides, you need to change your class name VehicleRegistration and your fields name also.

Comment: thanks already implemented this from the comments, and no change. I would like to not have to use select queries and use jpa and spring data.

Comment: try again like that please @Kaigo

Comment: I don't want to use jpa it causes conflicts in my project and is not that useful for nosql database like mongo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add @Entity to your vehicle_registration class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class vehicle_registration {
    /*
    This class must have the same name as the collection in mongodb
     */

    @Id
    String _id;

    Integer OwnID;
    Integer mileage_of_lasttransfer;
    Date date_of_registration;
    Date date_of_last_transfer;
    String registration_number;
    String UUID;
    String personUUID;
    String vehicleUUID;
    Date time_stamp;
}
```

It should work after that.

Comment: I'm not using JPA, So I don't have @Entity available and if I add the dependency in I get error `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

Answer (score 0):

@haticeSigirci lead me down the right path.

Solved it with

```
@Query("{registration_number: ?0}")
List<VehicleRegistration> getAllByRegistration_numberQuery(String registration_number);
```

[more info here](https://lishman.io/spring-data-mongodb-repository-queries)

Essentially, built in queries like `.findAll` work out of the box, however  custom ones need a @query statement.